# Form gets submitted when div container is shown

Tags: html

My form is submitted, when a `*ngIf` condition gets true. I have a `div-container` which should show the `submit` button only, when one of the two conditions i gave is `true`. The user should first select for which type of my company he wants to add an article and after that, he would be able to submit the form. Thats why i'd like to not show the `submit` button directly.

I created a stackblitz.io example, which shows the same behaviour - is this caused by a mistake on my own or is this a bug / feature that `submit` is triggerd by changing conditions?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fe8kgf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add type="button" to your button elements , type="submit" is the default if the typeis not specified in your btn element, so you have to specify that the type is button, otherwise it will submit your form

```
<button  type="button"> Area One</button>
<button  type="button"> Area One</button>
```

to avoid submitting

Comment: this works, thanks - is there any reason / documentation why the form is submitted when there is no type?

Comment: type="submit" is the default if the attribute is not specified, so you have to specify that the type is button, otherwise it will submit your form